# Site com animação

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, front-end

comecei a estudar web agora e gostaria de saber quais linguagens são usadas para fazer um site com animações como estes:

http://helpsanta.panic.lv/
http://www.mallonitrace.com/

Grato!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo visto os sites utilizam Javascript, HTML e css e o PHP, que são as bases para a web. Alem disso há um cms wordpress no ultimo site, que tem todas essas tecnologias já embutidas nele, mas recomendo que se quer aprender web, que começe a estudar o wordpress apenas quando tiver um certo conhecimento sobre as outras tecnologias.

Neste sentido voce pode estudar essas tres primeiras tecnologias que são voltadas mais ao front-end, ou seja a parte visual do site, e depois o PHP caso queira se aprimorar no back-end.

O wordpress irá te auxiliar a criar sites, ecommerces e até alguns sistemas de forma mais rapida, mas sem um conhecimento profundo, ficará um pouco engessado com este cms

Um bom site para pesquisar as tecnologias utilizadas na construção dos sites é o [builtwith](https://builtwith.com)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e pelas dicas!